# Rotation of coterminal angles with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-angles

How draw coterminal rotation as a show in figure.

[image]

Comment: coter ... what?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234167/how-one-can-draw-405-degree-angle-in-learning-material/234191 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60295/drawing-angles-greater-than-360%C2%BA-intikz

Comment: May also be of help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29147/spiral-spring-in-tikz

Comment: @Sebastiano That was Jake's second link, wasn't it?