# New command in TikZ with pgfkeys

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

The basic idea is from [How can I create new commands in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89773/how-can-i-create-new-commands-in-tikz)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,bending,decorations.text,positioning}

\def\centerarct[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)% Syntax: [draw options] (center) (start angle:end angle:radius)
{ \path[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(-#3+90)},{#5*sin(-#3+90)})$) arc [start angle={-#3+90}, end angle={-#4+90}, radius=#5)]; }

\pgfkeys{
    myvector/.is family,
    myvector,
    radius/.initial=4.5cm,
    line width/.initial =5mm,
    color/.initial=orange,
    text align/.initial=center,
    text/.initial=Label,
    raise/.initial=0mm
}

\newcommand\myvectorset[1]{\pgfkeys{myvector,#1}}

\def\myvector[#1](#2){
 \myvectorset{#1,
  radius/.get=\mbfradius,
  line width/.get=\mbflinewidth,
  color/.get=\mbfcolor,
  text align/.get=\mbftextalign,
  text/.get=\mbftext,
  raise/.get=\mbfraise
 }
 \centerarct[{Triangle[width=9mm,length=5mm]}-,draw=\mbfcolor,line  width=\mbflinewidth,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=\mbftextalign,text=\mbftext,raise=\mbfraise}}](#2)(180:1:\mbfradius);
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \myvector[text align=right,raise=-1.25mm](0,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It works. But unfortunately if I use

```
\myvector[text align={right,right indent=1cm},raise=-1.25mm](0,0);
```

the result is

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/text align/righ
t,right indent=1cm' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

I read about key handlers but I didn't found a way out.

Comment: Have you tried `\myvector[{text align={right,right indent=1cm}},raise=-1.25mm](0,0);`?

Comment: I tried it just now. No change.

Comment: I guess `text align=\mbftextalign` will treat `\mbftextalign` as **a** key instead of list of keys. I think it is better to use `/.style` to store list of keys.

Comment: Why do you need to even create all of those keys? Most of them are just standard keys anyway, including `text align`, aren't they?

Comment: For the mwe I changed the code to make it more easy. But in the end I want to use also own keys. The main goal is a command \myvector[options] (xcoord,ycoord); and options is key1=value1,key2=value2, ...; keys are standard, some are own and needed to calculate some thing for plotting the vector

Comment: I found https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34312/how-to-create-a-command-with-key-values/34318#34318 here. Perhaps this is a better way. But I need to undestand that first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the case where the `.expand once` handler is useful. In the `myvector` macro definition you have somewhere:

```
text align=\mbftextalign
```

What you want is to set `text align` to the expansion of the `\mbftextalign` macro. You can do this easily with:

```
text align/.expand once=\mbftextalign
```

Of course, you should do the same modification with the other keys where expansion is needed.

Comment: This solves it!