# Archimedean spiral in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am fairly new to LaTeX and have not actually worked with TikZ yet. Is ist possible to draw an Archimedean spiral starting at the coordinate origin? I have read the TikZ description but did not find what I was looking for.

Comment: You can use [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29154/12571), changing `0.002*\t*\t` to `0.02*\t`, for example.