# How can I write a spiral symbol?

Tags: symbols, pdftex

How can I get a spiral like

[image]

There seems to be a spiral-like unicode codepoint: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/aa5c/index.htm

I tried

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Color
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.95}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{43612}{\spiral}

%document
\begin{document}{\textcolor{lightgray}{a}}\spiral{\textcolor{lightgray}{b}}
\end{document}
```

but I got

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.13 ...document}{\textcolor{lightgray}{a}}\spiral
                                              {\textcolor{lightgray}{b}}
```

edit: I know [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5645). None of the answers gave me a spiral symbol.

Comment: pdf (I added the pdftex tag)

Comment: Now that unicode codepoint *calls* `\spiral` but `\spiral` isn't defined.

Comment: Related: [spiral spring in tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29147/3954).

Comment: can't you just save the image you posted as spiral.png then use `\includegraphics[height=1em]{spiral}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought there is probably a nicer solution (I am asking this question because people keep writing spirals on write-math.com - I don't need it myself)

Comment: You can try to find a spiral symbol in the [comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) (I haven't found any, but I didn't look very thoroughly): Note that the font that you use in the LaTeX document should contain this particular character. I don't think this is the case...

Comment: Unicode U+AA5C belongs to the Cham block, allocated for the Cham script (see http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UAA00.pdf). You may be possibly find a font containing it and then use its glyph for getting a graphics to include.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would imagine that if font samples are viewable, they're in the public domain. As such, a search for [font with spiral symbol](https://www.google.ca/webhp?#q=font+with+spiral+symbol) yields a host of ideas.

Below I've used the [Altemus Spirals Regular](http://www.linotype.com/423518/altemus-spirals-regular-product.html) font's [PDF sample](http://image.linotype.com/samples/hirespdf/423518.pdf):

[image]

Then you can clip out the element you're interested in:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\spiral}[1][]{\includegraphics[
  height=.7\baselineskip,
  origin=c,% For rotation purposes, rotate around centre
  viewport=154mm 173mm 176mm 194mm,clip,
  #1% Any other graphicx options
  ]{altemus_spiral_regular}%
}
\begin{document}
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{\spiral}}

\spiral{}
\spiral[angle=90]
\reflectbox{\spiral}

A regular \spiral{} together with text and even \spiral[angle=180] rotated.
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if you have access to a font containing a spiral, you can use XeLaTeX or LauLaTeX directly.

Answer (score 7):

I downloaded the SVG Outline from the [link you provided](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/aa5c/index.htm) and exported it to a [TikZ path using Inkscape](https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz).  Here is the result after some adjustments by hand:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\spiral{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[y=.009ex,x=.009ex,yscale=-1]
    \path[fill] (74.2500,379.5469) -- (62.4375,373.3594) .. controls
      (83.4375,365.2031) and (99.6563,356.1563) .. (111.0938,346.2188) .. controls
      (122.5313,336.2813) and (131.0625,324.9375) .. (136.6875,312.1875) .. controls
      (142.3125,299.4375) and (145.1250,284.4375) .. (145.1250,267.1875) .. controls
      (145.1250,256.6875) and (141.9375,247.5000) .. (135.5625,239.6250) .. controls
      (129.1875,231.7500) and (121.7813,226.3125) .. (113.3438,223.3125) .. controls
      (104.9063,220.3125) and (95.6250,218.8125) .. (85.5000,218.8125) .. controls
      (75.3750,218.8125) and (66.0937,220.3125) .. (57.6562,223.3125) .. controls
      (49.2187,226.3125) and (41.8125,231.7500) .. (35.4375,239.6250) .. controls
      (29.0625,247.5000) and (25.8750,256.6875) .. (25.8750,267.1875) .. controls
      (25.8750,277.6875) and (27.3750,286.9687) .. (30.3750,295.0312) .. controls
      (33.3750,303.0937) and (38.1563,308.9063) .. (44.7188,312.4688) .. controls
      (51.2813,316.0313) and (59.2500,317.8125) .. (68.6250,317.8125) .. controls
      (73.6875,317.8125) and (77.5782,316.7813) .. (80.2969,314.7188) .. controls
      (83.0156,312.6563) and (85.2187,309.7500) .. (86.9062,306.0000) .. controls
      (88.5937,302.2500) and (89.4375,297.3750) .. (89.4375,291.3750) .. controls
      (89.0625,288.3750) and (88.4063,285.6563) .. (87.4688,283.2188) .. controls
      (86.5313,280.7813) and (85.0313,278.9063) .. (82.9688,277.5938) .. controls
      (80.9063,276.2813) and (78.3750,275.6250) .. (75.3750,275.6250) .. controls
      (72.9375,275.6250) and (70.5469,277.1250) .. (68.2031,280.1250) .. controls
      (65.8594,283.1250) and (63.7500,288.4219) .. (61.8750,296.0156) --
      (57.6562,295.8750) .. controls (55.5937,295.8750) and (54.0937,295.4063) ..
      (53.1562,294.4688) .. controls (52.2187,293.5313) and (51.7500,292.5000) ..
      (51.7500,291.3750) .. controls (51.7500,286.5000) and (52.6875,281.7187) ..
      (54.5625,277.0312) .. controls (56.4375,272.3437) and (59.2500,268.5000) ..
      (63.0000,265.5000) .. controls (66.7500,262.5000) and (70.8750,261.0000) ..
      (75.3750,261.0000) .. controls (80.6250,261.0000) and (85.4063,262.1250) ..
      (89.7188,264.3750) .. controls (94.0313,266.6250) and (97.4063,270.0937) ..
      (99.8438,274.7812) .. controls (102.2813,279.4687) and (103.5000,285.0000) ..
      (103.5000,291.3750) .. controls (103.5000,299.6250) and (102.3750,306.5625) ..
      (100.1250,312.1875) .. controls (97.8750,317.8125) and (94.0313,322.5937) ..
      (88.5938,326.5312) .. controls (83.1563,330.4687) and (76.5000,332.4375) ..
      (68.6250,332.4375) .. controls (57.3750,332.4375) and (47.0625,329.8125) ..
      (37.6875,324.5625) .. controls (28.3125,319.3125) and (21.5625,311.5313) ..
      (17.4375,301.2188) .. controls (13.3125,290.9063) and (11.2500,279.5625) ..
      (11.2500,267.1875) .. controls (11.2500,254.0625) and (14.2500,241.9687) ..
      (20.2500,230.9062) .. controls (26.2500,219.8437) and (35.1563,211.3125) ..
      (46.9688,205.3125) .. controls (58.7813,199.3125) and (71.6250,196.3125) ..
      (85.5000,196.3125) .. controls (99.3750,196.3125) and (112.2187,199.3125) ..
      (124.0312,205.3125) .. controls (135.8437,211.3125) and (144.7500,219.8437) ..
      (150.7500,230.9062) .. controls (156.7500,241.9687) and (159.7500,254.0625) ..
      (159.7500,267.1875) .. controls (159.7500,287.4375) and (156.5625,304.7813) ..
      (150.1875,319.2188) .. controls (143.8125,333.6563) and (134.0625,346.1250) ..
      (120.9375,356.6250) .. controls (107.8125,367.1250) and (92.2500,374.7656) ..
      (74.2500,379.5469) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\Huge A\spiral B
\LARGE A\spiral B
\Large A\spiral B
\large A\spiral B
A\spiral B
\small A\spiral B
\footnotesize A\spiral B
\scriptsize A\spiral B
\tiny A\spiral B

\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

Even though you don't want to use XeLaTeX, this might be useful to someone else.  The [Code2000 font](https://web.archive.org/web/20101122142710/http://code2000.net/code2000_page.htm) (shareware with odd license) and [Noto Sans Cham](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) possess this particular character.  You may use it like

```
\fontspec{CODE2000.TTF}꩜
```

or

```
\fontspec{CODE2000.TTF}^^^^aa5c
```

Here is a comparison of the fake TikZ symbol with the one from Code2000 and from Noto Sans Cham:

> [image]

Because Noto Sans Cham only covers the Cham range of Unicode the Latin letters are missing and replaced by rectangles.

Comment: I've just added this to my symbol database: http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/symbol/?id=1704 - thank you for creating the solution!