# Where would I get a symbol for a spiral galaxy?

Tags: symbols

I was hoping there was some astronomy or astrology symbol for the Milky Way, but no luck so far. Anyone have a clever way I could make such a symbol, perhaps one that resembles a spiral galaxy?

Some people have taken this question to be about printing a simple spiral in LaTeX. But most spiral galaxies do not resemble spirals. The Milky Way, for example, has quite a few arms.

One might argue that it resembles an asterisk whose pixels undergo a rotation about the asterisk center, where the angle of rotation is proportional to the pixel radius. But I'm not sure how one would accomplish that kind of rotation in LaTeX — it's just the best thought I've had so far.

I've also looked through the comprehensive list of LaTeX symbols, and I do not see one which resembles a spiral galaxy.

Comment: Maybe take an galaxy icon and include it as image https://www.google.de/search?hl=de&q=icon%20galaxy

Comment: Apparently none of the close-voters know the difference between a spiral and a spiral galaxy ;-)

Comment: Vote to reopen: This question is less specific. A galaxy symbol is not necessarily a spiral,  even if it is one "that perhaps resembles a spiral galaxy". For instance, a rotated  `\S` could be a legitimate answer here (resemble a barred spiral galaxy) , but not in the linked question.

Comment: @Fran Given that the question is not very specific about what sort of galaxy symbol is required, and spiral galaxies are mentioned and are widely recognised as"galaxies", I don't see the case for reopening...

Comment: @Andrew Yes, spiral galaxies are the most typical galaxies, but the point is that even these galaxies can be represented by just a spiral curve (and then it is OK answer in [How can I write a spiral symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231517/how-can-i-write-a-spiral-symbol)) or with something else (that is not a valid answer in that question, but it is perfectly valid here).

Comment: [How to look up a symbo](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)

Comment: Okay, just coming back from vacation with no internet, and for sure, this is *not* a duplicate. The spirals in the linked question are single-arm spirals, but a spiral galaxy has lots of arms. It's more like if you rotated different points in an asterisk proportional to the radius from the asterisk center.

Comment: @Dr.JohnnyMohawk: How about you use MS Paint and draw it as an example. That would make things clearer and perhaps result in symbol-like *drawings* being made (using a graphics package like [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)) instead of straight-up symbols.

Comment: You are lucky man! Vacation without of internet tyranny! What a luxury :-). Seriously: I doubt that exist a spiral symbol with many arms. A solution seems to be draw it by some program (pstrick, tikz) .

Comment: Here are a bunch of different representations that have been used for spiral galaxies in the past (specifically ours): http://www.native-science.net/MilkyWay.Centre.htm I'd really take any of those symbols, but the best representation of the spiral galaxy would be the second image.

Comment: Have you seen https://openclipart.org/detail/217472/galaxy, https://openclipart.org/detail/211401/spiral-galaxy, and https://openclipart.org/detail/167636/galaxy ?

Comment: @Thérèse Thanks! The second link is exactly what I'm looking for. Do you know how one would typeset this as a character instead of as an image? Or is it simpler just to do `\includegraphics`?

Comment: You could create your own font with just that symbol, but it wouldn’t make for accessibility unless the symbol is in Unicode. It’s probably best to use this approach: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412868

Answer (score 5):

A creation of the galaxy symbol to spire with a `\newcommand{\galaxy}`. This picture is been by me created with a vectorial software. The `.pdf` file is no longer available but you can use the image given.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\galaxy}{\includegraphics[width=0.13in]{image}}
\begin{document}
This is a galaxy spiral \galaxy.
\end{document}
```

Here is the image converted (from png) to hi-res jpeg:

[image]