# Planet Icons: Non-Astronomical Symbols

Tags: symbols, color, packages

In the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) we know that there are many packages where there are differents astronomical symbols. I have taken the list of the index from the guide.

```
Table 315: wasysym Astronomical Symbols . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 122
Table 316: marvosym Astronomical Symbols . .. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 122
Table 317: fontawesome Astronomical Symbols . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 123
Table 318: mathabx Astronomical Symbols . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 123
Table 319: stix Astronomical Symbols . . . . .  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 123
```

My question is: is there a package that draws the planets with the characteristics of each of them? For example Saturn (with the ring that characterizes it), our Earth, or fixed stars, etc.?

Comment: For the colored planets: the `graphicx` package with some external pictures (as https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Planets_are_us.png).

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thank you for your comment. I remember that peraphs there is a package with the planets. But I not wanted to use the graphicx package :-( to insert the icon with an image....now I seen an answer...that is very very nice.

Comment: @downvoter: What is the reason of your downvote? Thank you for an answer of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching this site for other astronomical icons, I have immediately finded this great answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483433/204509. One can use the same technique for the planets: use some random image off the internet and include it as image. With http://cdn30.us1.fansshare.com/image/cartoonplanet/vector-cartoon-planet-icons-579074540.jpg one gets

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\mercury}{\includegraphics[height=1em]{mercury}}
\newcommand{\venus}{\includegraphics[height=1em]{venus}}
\newcommand{\earth}{\includegraphics[height=1em]{earth}}
\newcommand{\mars}{\includegraphics[height=1em]{mars}}
\newcommand{\jupiter}{\includegraphics[height=1em]{jupiter}}
\newcommand{\saturn}{\includegraphics[height=1em]{saturn}}
\newcommand{\uranus}{\includegraphics[height=1em]{uranus}}
\newcommand{\neptun}{\includegraphics[height=1em]{neptun}}

\begin{document}

\mercury
\venus
\earth
\mars
\jupiter
\saturn
\uranus
\neptun

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My sincere and best compliments for your work.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen that from **2020/04/19** there is a specific package named [tikz-planets](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-planets/planets-doc.pdf) to illustrate the planets of the solar system.
Just I put a screenshot of page 5 and the link of the file [planets.sty](https://framagit.org/Moutmout/tikz-planets/-/blob/master/planets.sty)

[image]